# How to unit test code inside validate method nuxtjs vuejs jest

Tags: vue.js, unit-testing, jestjs, nuxt.js, vue-test-utils

I have code inside [validate method](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/components-glossary/validate/) if condition true it returns true else false.
I want to test that code. Is there any way to do it.

Comment: `validate` is not really meant for Jest tests, `validate` is for runtime validations. What did you tried so far?

Comment: @kissu I would really appreciate if you understand the **need** of the question rather than saying what is **meant**. Anyway I am happy you took interest in my question.

Answer (score 0):

So usually **asyncData method** and **validate** method are part of nuxt not vuejs and can't be tested usually but we do want to test it if it was possible.

**Why test validate** : As we are working on a long project we want to test it if every condition works as expected, someone's change didn't hinder the working of this method and thus i came around with solution to call that method manually and pass parameters to it accordingly.

```
// example.vue
validate({ params, query }) {
    if (params.includes("abc" && query["something"])) {
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }
```

```
// example.test.js
import index from "example.vue"

describe("test", () => {
  it("Check validate method", async () => {
    // Check when query present
    const params = {
      abc: "abc"
    };
    const query = {
      something: "abc"
    };
    const validate = Index.validate({ params, $constants, query });
    expect(validate).toBe(true); // or false
  });
});
```